# How to get the row number from a while loop of mysql_fetch_array for each loop?

Tags: mysql, while-loop

I have a simple while loop like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

}
```

It fetches many rows one by one and it is fine. 
But i have add some extra features according to the row number.

- when row number=1( first row)-do something
- when row number=2( second row)-do something new

how can i get that ROW NUMBER of the each row?

Comment: Why not just count it in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Add a count variable:

```
$count = 1;
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
    // do your work here
    $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to include the row number in your select SQL. So updated your MySQL SQL Statement that fetches the rows, to include the row number as follows.

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘row_number’, * from your_table, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
```

This will create a variable `rownum`, initialize with value `0` & increase it by `1` for every record. Each `row` will have a column called `row_number` with ascending number starting from 1.

Then in your `while... loop` check for this `row_number` value and do processing accordingly.

Reference: [See this post for another approach that involves creating a separate variable in SQL statement](http://www.fromdual.com/ranking-mysql-results).

Answer (score 0):

add an extra field in the select called `row` like this

```
SELECT @row:=IFNULL(@row,0)+1 as row,
       your_columns
  FROM your_tables
```